# Is it possible to create a website and avoid the built-in ASP.NET controls with ASP.NET Webforms but still get the same functionality?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is it possible to create a website and avoid the built-in ASP.NET controls with ASP.NET Webforms but still get the same functionality?

As stated on various websites, using built-in ASP.NET controls vs HTML controls does represent both an advantage but also a disadvantage, so I'm curious to find out if it's possible to avoid the built-in ASP.NET controls but still get the same functionality as the controls would offer?

I know about MVC and I do not plan to use it, since I'm running ASP.NET through MONO.

Comment: what you mean by efficient? there can be loads of factors which determines the efficiency of a web site

Comment: Please explain what issue you are trying to solve here.

Comment: I tend to only find the ASP.NET controls a disadvantage in that they don't always do exactly what I want, just something close to it. I wouldn't personally say as a general rule that using them can be a disadvantage. I personally use ASP.NET controls where appropriate and HTML controls when needed and roll my own controls up if neither of them are quite up for the job (or there is some HTML construct I find myself regularly using).

Comment: "avoid the built-in ASP.NET controls but still get the same functionality as the controls would offer" - if you want the exact same functionality surely by some theorem then they would be the same control...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ASP.NET/MVC](http://asp.net/mvc) - it doesn't use any of the webforms controls.

---

Update, seeing as MVC is not an option:

Of course, you *could* just write your own controls from scratch or some third party controls.

I don't see any benefit in that. If you are going to use webforms, use the built in controls when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just plain old html control in ASP.NET web forms. You have to add the runat="server" to the html control and you can use it on the server side. You could build a whole site that way. Although technically that's the literal control. I supposed you could write the whole page using inline code and plain old html . https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx I'm Not sure what mono supports.